# iOS 12 autofill password stored to wrong associated domain

Tags: ios, xcode, passwords, autofill, associated-domains

I have two variants of my iOS 12 app, each associated with a different domain (association works fine as checked via swcd in Console.app).

The app with Bundle ID com.company.baseName.dev1 is successfully associated with dev1.example.com.

The app with Bundle ID com.company.baseName.dev2 is successfully associated with dev2.example.com.

So far so good. But autofill password stores app passwords not based on domain of current app but rather domain of app which first stored a password.

If I first run dev1 app, password is stored to dev1 domain. Then if I run dev2 app, password is also stored in dev1 domain. And vice versa. If  I delete the password for dev1 domain and run dev2, password is now stored in dev2 domain for this run and subsequent runs of both dev1 and dev2. It's like iOS sees dev1 and dev2 as the same app even though I've verified e.g. via `Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier` that bundle IDs are correct and thoroughly checked every thing else I can think of.

Seems like an Apple bug?

Comment: Sounds like it is stored under the teamid.. are you using the sharedwebcredentials API?

Comment: Did you specify the webcredentjals: prefix/service for the domains and is your Apple-App-site-Association File different (i.e. only contains one bundle) for both domains.

Comment: Yes, webcredentials line is correct in entitlements file and each apple-app-site-association file contains single (correct) app ID. swcd logs confirm correct apple-app-site-association file checked and correct app ID association made for both apps on startup.

Comment: To be explicit, if I delete one of the apps on a device then re-run with xcode I get the following swcd log in console: ```Updated app ID 'xx.com.xx.xx.dev1', domain 'dev1.xx.xx', flags 0x0 < > -> 0x2 < SiteApproved > on check```. So seems there is no issue with domain/app ID association....